# Is it possible to specify a cluster inside a subgraph

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like to create several clusters inside a subgraph like the following :

```
subgraph sub {
    rank=same;
    subgraph cluster_test {
        p4;
        p5;
        p6;
    }

    subgraph cluster_t {
        p1;
        p2;
        p3;
    }
}
```

My aim is to have several clusters (which group the nodes together) at the same rank. However it seems clusters do not work inside subgraphs. Is there a way around that ?

Answer (score 1):

`rank=same` can't apply across clusters.  (yes, it would be nice).  Clusters are laid out independently, `rank=same` would require dependent layout.
Also `rank=same` really applies to nodes within a subgraph, not a cluster, that can consist of nodes in multiple ranks.
Clusters are positioned based on the ranks of the enclosed nodes, but to try to get multiple clusters horizontally aligned, try embedding then within a parental cluster, like so (or using invisible edges to adjust ranking):

```
digraph D {
 subgraph cluster_outer{
    subgraph cluster_test {
        p4;
        p5;
        p6;
    }

    subgraph cluster_t {
        p1;
        p2;
        p3;
    }
   graph [peripheries=0]   // if you don't want the extra box
}
}
```

Giving:
[[image: 1]